# Windows 7 Backup on Synology: Smartcard Certificate Authority Untrusted

Tags: backup, nas, certificate, synology-diskstation

On setting up a backup for the NAS on W10 Pro 20H2, get the following COM error `0x80090352`:

> An untrusted certificate authority was detected While processing the smartcard certificate used for authentication. Please contact your system administrator.

The certificate on the Synology NAS is the basic one set up with LetsEncrypt: so named **storage.synology.me**. Presumably Windows takes a copy of this certificate and sets the untrusted flag. However, there seems nothing in the certificate that indicates it's a smartcard cert- does the W7 backup program make the conversion? There's nothing like a copy of it in the *MMC > Certificates* store either.

Also, when different NAS subdirectories are specified, the W7 backup program tends to want to randomly select NAS subdirectories as candidate for either a `0X80070043` (Network Name cannot be found) or the above `0x80090352`. Thus it is possible to reselect a subdirectory in the *Select a Network Location* dialog to get a different error.

Is there something in the Windows Group Policy settings causing this, or can anything more be done on the NAS side?

As a matter of interest, this issue with the same NAS never arose on another system with W10 Home edition installed, and the newer W10 "*Backup Using File History*" has no issue writing to any directory on the NAS drive.

Comment: Which LetsEncrypt CA signed the certificate?

Comment: To set it up, followed this [guide](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Network/How_to_enable_HTTPS_and_create_a_certificate_signing_request_on_your_Synology_NAS) with the Synology DDNS. Not sure how to ascertain what CA is used- is it unique for Synology DDNS?

Comment: Let’sEncrypt has two root CA one is due to expire soon, the other is the “active” one, but certain legacy devices can’t support it.  Trying to determine if the untrusted status of the certificate is legitimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backup proceeded once the [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) Best Practices option for TLS was applied. Please refer to the [LetsEncrypt thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/windows-7-backup-untrusted-certificate/151779) for details.